# single mud tube coming down from ceiling

Tags: ceiling, termite

I have a vaulted ceiling in my dining room. About a week ago I saw something coming down from the ceiling.  When I knocked it off, I realized it was a mud tube. There is a tiny hole left in the ceiling.  Nothing has come back. I continue to watch to see if any more appear. I checked around outside and can find no mud tubes going up the walls from the ground.  I am very concerned.  Could anything else make a small mud tube coming down from the ceiling?

Comment: A photo would be helpful, sheetrock mud? Black earth mud all kinds of things come to mind that a photo would help explain.

Comment: Also where on the planet are you located?

Comment: Also, watch the outside area at the peaks, eaves, soffits, and see if you see activity from bees, wasps, or even birds.

Comment: Always take photos  and try to keep a sample in ziplock bag.    If you suspect termites, then call a professional to search for evidence that would confirm / refute